# binary back to List<Int16>

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written a list of values to a binary file using the binary writer.

I was wondering if someone could show me how I could extract the list of int16 values back from this binary file?

Thanks in advance

```
using (var file = File.Create(fileName))
using (view.IncidentWriter = new BinaryWriter(file))
{
    foreach (short dataItem in view.Data)
    {
        view.IncidentWriter.Write(dataItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: How **exactly** did you write them? any preamble such as item count?

Comment: using the following, I edited above post to include the way it was written

Answer (score 5):

The [binary reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) is binary writer's friend, you can make it yours

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to prefix the data with the expected count:

```
        var list = new List<short>{1,2,3,4,5};
        using (var file = File.Create("my.data"))
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(file))
        {
            writer.Write(list.Count);
            foreach(var item in list) writer.Write(item);
        }

        using (var file = File.OpenRead("my.data"))
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file))
        {
            int count = reader.ReadInt32();
            list = new List<short>(count);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                list.Add(reader.ReadInt16());
        }
```

Otherwise, you have to detect EOF, which is easy enough with a `Stream`, but a pain with a `BinaryReader`.